# Did the dual booster landing timing change with USSF-44?

Tags: landing, falcon-heavy

Falcon Heavy, on its fourth flight, landed its two core boosters via RTLS at LZ-1 and LZ-2.

Previous F-H launches the two cores have landed at LZ-1/2 within a second or two of each other. So much so, it looks great and co-ordinated.

But a rough counting as they landed suggests that the boosters on USSF-44 landed closer to 5 seconds apart. This seems like a change from the past.

Do we know if this was on purpose, and if so, to what end?

Comment: The absolute synchronity of the first landing was an "accident". In the video feed it was obvious quite early that there was some time difference between the boosters actions which makes sense. It depends on the orioentation of the stack at time of separation (to the sides or one "up" and one "dowwn"?) and how much they have to rorate to get in the right attitude after sep...